# Initial value for RunningValue() SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2008-r2

I am designing a report that need to get the cumulative value. I am using the `RunningValue()` function for it. The issue is the value always starts from 0.  Is it possible to get an initial value and then do the `RunningValue()` from it?

Thanks

**[EDITED]**

This is what I need.  The initial value comes from the total of accountIDs in a given date and the runningvalue() would start to add more accountIDs from it

[image]

Comment: when you say `value always starts from 0` what value do u mean? the first row of the running value will take the first value, so technically its not 0.

Comment: You got it, is not always that the value starts from 0, but it starts from a number below the number i need. The initial value i need is the total of accountid's in a given date, and then the runningvalue() would start to count from it.

Comment: so whats your actual requirement. paste some sample data and expected resultset.

Comment: The initial value i need is the total of accountid's (the report is for dynamics CRM) in a given date, and then the runningvalue() would start to add more accountid's from it.

Comment: So the starting value is coming from a sum of other data in the dataset?  If not, where is this starting value coming from?

Comment: Yes, the value i need is in the data set, i've already tried to sum it and them aggregate to RunningValue, but the resulted number was below the expected

Comment: i need something like: `=Count(Fields!accountid)+RunningValue(CountDistinct(Fields!accountid.Value),sum,nothing)`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried...

```
=RunningValue(*condition*) + starting_value
```

For example setting the value of the third column in the image below to

```
=RunningValue(CInt(Fields!Val.Value), Sum, "DataSet1") + 10
```

Gives

[image]

Comment: That would help. But i need a dynamic initial value, that cames from the sum of the accountid's in a given date and then the RunningValue() would start to add more accountid's from that day